# Missing package

Tags: miktex, installing

I have just installed MiKTeX and Texmaker to use latex. But as I run the program for a file the following error occurred. I searched online and tried to download the package from https://ctan.org/pkg/download?lang=en . Then I put the file into the latex folder, but it's still not working. Is the problem because of missing files or something else?

[image: x]

Comment: Update your MikTeX system with the MikTeX Console, then go to the Console and select "Tasks > Update package database". If you have installed MikTeX in multi-user mode you have to perform these two steps once in Admin and once in User mode. Then try to re-run the file and accept any on-the-fly installation windows that might pop up.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. But I tried to fix it following your steps and another error occurred, I could not send the screenshots in the comment so I'll just describe it, a window pops out saying the connection to {host} could not be established, since I am currently in China and using the VPN, I check the proxy server settings, as recommended. But the same window still pops out showing it couldn't connect, can you give me any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about connection issues and VPNs. I have never experienced any of those...

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?